# How to take value from input type="text" and use it on another page?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the value from my input type="text", in login page, which have, name and matrix no and paste it on another page

Here's my question. how do I locate my input value from login page and use it on another page using javascript?

for ex: 
user input the name and matrix no, and then click login button .. the login button will navigate the user to the next page .. and on the next page, on the header part .. the name and matrix no will be displayed there

Comment: You should clarify your question. It's very unclear as to what you want to do. You talk about `input` (form fields), `location.search...` (which implies something with a QueryString), and a login page (session Cookie?). And why and for what do you actually need that value. Depending on that there are a lot of different solutions.

Comment: I already edit the question .. I just wanna to know, how to get the input value from login page and use that value on another page

Comment: Is "another page" at same origin as first `document`?

Comment: How will the user get to the other page? Do you mean: "use JavaScript to navigate to another page, and use the input once you're on that page", or do you mean "store the input so at some future time when the user navigates to another page the input will still be available"?

Comment: let me clarify this .. ex: user input the name and matrix no, and then click login button .. the login button will navigate the user to the next page .. and on the next page, on the header part .. the name and matrix no will be displayed there

Comment: @guest271314 .. no .. if it is , I know how to do it .. when user click login button, the system will pop up the modal box and display the name and matrix no .. but now I want that data to be on the next page .. not on the same page .. hope someone get me on this qq